# Angular2 - HTTP RequestOptions HEADERS

Tags: angular, http, typescript, tslint

I currently have an issue with tslint and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to send an HTTP GET request using HTTP provided by the Angular2 framework. With this request, I must specify the content-type and the bearer authentication token.

Example of my code:

```
let headers = new Headers();
let authToken = this._user.getUser().JWT;
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this._http.get('http://' + url '/', options)
            .timeout(3000)
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
```

This works, however, tslint is complaining that

> "TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'. Types of property 'headers'
>   are incompatible. Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
>   Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>   Property 'keys' is missing in type 'Headers'."

I appreciate the support.

Comment: consider use const instead of let for both options and headers

Answer (score 201, accepted):

**Update**

As of today, `@angular/http` has been [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/http/Headers), and `@angular/common/http` should be used instead. So the best way to work with http headers is to import `import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';` ([documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)).

**Old answer**

The `Headers` type you are supposed to import is `import { Headers } from '@angular/http';`.

Check your imports

Comment: That was it! I'm using Phpstorm and is usually pretty good and clearly showing me that I've missed a dependency but didn't this time. Furthermore, I don't find the tslint message very clear. Cheers :)

Comment: Somehow there is a Headers class even if you don't import it. So you have to make sure you import the right one (see answer above) in order for it to work.

Comment: For Angular 5, this helped me `import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';` [DOCUMENTATION](https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions)

Comment: @Abhi It says in the docs that *Headers* is deprecated and we should use *HttpHeaders* from *@angular/common/http* instead. But that doesn't really work... Thoughts?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana I find [THIS](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/the-new-http-client-in-angular-4-3-754bd3ff83a8) as a good referrence

Comment: `@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'Http'.` every article says different

Comment: `/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'Headers'.` wtf

Answer (score 9):

You have to update headers by:

```
let headers =  {headers: new  HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})};
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update for Angular 5**

```
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

I found this in the comments from the correct answer, so If this helps somebody, good luck.

Documentation: https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions

Comment: This is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it had change in the last days. check the documentation, now is `import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';`

Answer (score 2):

// example of headers of content type Json

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

const Url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
const headers = new Headers;
const body = JSON.stringify({
title: "data" 
});
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.post(Url, body, { headers: headers })
.pipe(map((res => res)));
```