# Asp.net core webapi getting null value posted from Angular4 app

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am new to `Angular4` and in a situation to deliver the stuff quickly so have no time to learn it thoroughly so pardon if my question seems childish:

From my `Asp.Net Web API` I have `Confirmemail API` which has to be called from Angular4 application, looks like this:

**Asp.net WebApi:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object>ConfirmEmail([FromBody] string userid,[FromBody] string code)
{
}
```

**In Angular4 Service API:**

```
ConfirmEmail(userid,code)
{           
    let url =`api/account/ConfirmEmail`;
    let data= `userid=${userid}&code=${code}`;
    console.log(data);
    return this.http.post(url,data);
}
```

Here, I checked in console.log the data is coming properly, but at the webapi side I am finding these strings null. I tried removing [FromBody] but it didn't worked with me.

I am really clueless what is missing, it is almost one day preparing all these things but have not got any success. Do you guys have any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `post` data to your `API` from angular app try this in **angular**:

```
let url ="api/account/ConfirmEmail";

var userInfo = { "userid":userid, "code":code }
let content = JSON.stringify(userInfo);

let headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

return this.http.post(url, content, { headers: headers, responseType: 'text'});
```

and in your `API` for receive your request body and **deserialize** this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object>ConfirmEmail([FromBody] UserInfo userInfo)
{

}

Public Class UserInfo
{
  public long userid {get; set;}
  public long code {get; set;}
}
```

For send your data in **url** you should use http `get` method like this:

**Angular:**

```
let Params = new HttpParams();

Params = Params.append("userid", userid);
Params = Params.append("code", code);

return this.http.get(url , { params: Params });
```

**Web API:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<object>ConfirmEmail(string userid, string code)
{
}
```

Comment: While both the answers are helpful

Comment: Hi Hasan, Please make necessary changes in the answer to get whole picture at single shot for other users and I will make the answer.

Comment: like request option didn't worked for me, so I tried like this let headers = new HttpHeaders(); headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); return this.http.post(url,data,{ headers: headers, responseType: 'text' });

Comment: @JaidevKhatri after i search in web `requestOption` not supported in new version of `httpClient` and i recommend not use this

Comment: @JaidevKhatri i add option

Answer (score 2):

You can make an object of both userid and code and convert to string using `JSON.stringify(data);`

```
let url =`api/account/ConfirmEmail`;
let userObj = {'userid':userid,'code':code};
let data= JSON.stringify(userObj);
return this.http.post(url,data);
```

and access it as

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object>ConfirmEmail([FromBody] User userObj)
{

}
```

Comment: That is another way in my mind, but would like if I like to have simple parameter passing

Comment: This is how http post works! if you want parameter passing you can use httpget

Comment: Tried your solution, showing error as unsupported media type.

Comment: @Sajeetharan this is the deference among my answer and your answer

Comment: @HasanFathi yes i understand :)

Comment: error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
      Property 'forEach' is missing in type 'HttpHeaders'.

Comment: @JaidevKhatri please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205570/angular2-http-requestoptions-headers

Comment: you can mark only one and upvote both :) . i think hasan's answer deserved to be chosen as correct

Comment: why data convert to **JSON.Stringfy()** ?