# .net Core Angular 6 API [FromBody] is null when published

Tags: c#, angular, api, http, asp.net-core

I have a problem with my API.

So when I'm in my IDE and run my code through *ng serve* and *dotnet run* everything works fine and I get values in my backend.
But when I publish my code and try it on my server the FromBody var is null.

Also in the Chrome Dev Tools, I see the values in the Request Payload.

Why the Oberservable?
Because that is my result and I do not know the other way.

**Broken API**

Working in IDE but not when published

My TypeScript

```
signupUser(user: User): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.http.post<boolean>('api/user/signupuser', user);
}
```

My C#

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SignUpUser([FromBody]User user)
{
    return UserBusinessLayer.SignUpUser(user);
}
```

**Working API**

Working in IDE and when published

TypeScript

```
loginUser(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.http.post<boolean>('api/user/loginuser', {email: email, password: password});
}
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public bool LoginUser([FromBody]User user)
{
    return UserBusinessLayer.LoginUser(user);
}
```

Comment: what are the headers on the request? What is your content-Type?

Comment: you mean this? https://i.imgur.com/CDsPXnC.png

Comment: From that picture it shows you getting a 500 error, is that because user is null?

Comment: Yes, because its null

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852189/asp-net-core-webapi-getting-null-value-posted-from-angular4-app/48852315#48852315

Comment: Well, with JSON.stringify i get a 415 Status Code "unsupported media type"

Answer (score 0):

Through testing I found an exception.

Turns out the `User` object was always *null* because it **couldn't be casted**.

I had a telephone number in the object stored as `int`. But the number had too many numbers.

So I used a `string` instead and everything works fine now.