# Type Headers is not assignable to type HttpHeaders in TypeScript and Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, postman

I am new to `TypeScript` and am learning to do a simple authentication tutorial. For the backend I am using `Express`, and frontend I am using `Angular 9`. I researched the error a lot as there are good resources online but I could not understand why none applied to my case.

I receive the following error:

> Error: src/app/services/auth.service.ts:19:79 - error TS2769: No
> overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
> error.
> Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } | undefined'.
> Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
> Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
>
> 19     return
> this.httpCient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user,
> {headers: headers}).pipe(map(res => res));

So on both functions `registerUser(user)` and `authenticate(user)` the errors seems to be in this line:

```
return this.httpCient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers}).pipe(map(res => res));
```

Below the code that is causing the issue:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  registerUser(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, {headers: headers}).pipe(map(res => res));
  }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, {headers: headers}).pipe(map(res => res));
  }
}
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735960/argument-of-type-headerheader-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-requ) to help me solve the problem but did not work because I am using `Angular 9` and the `http` module is now replaced with `HttpClient, HttpHeaders` from `'@angular/common/http';`. So I was able to follow and partially solved it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205570/angular2-http-requestoptions-headers) was useful too as general knowledge but it deals with `Angular 2` and could not find a useful answer.

Please if anyone had the same error please share how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HttpClient` expects `HttpHeaders` as parameter. (`Headers` object was used before the `HttpClient` was introduced and it is not compatible with the `HttpClient`.) So for example following could work:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
});
return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, httpOptions);
```

See some more details and example here:
https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

Don't forget to subscribe to the returned `Observable` because otherwise the request will not be sent. (Observables are lazy.)

Comment: Thanks I see what happened. Can you please explain what you mean with "Don't forget to subscribe to the returned Observable" in order to take care of the request please? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The `registerUser` and `authenticateUser` funtions return an `RxJS` `Observable` because the methods of `HttpClient` return it. If you have an `Observable` you need to have a subscription for it, for example this way: `observable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));`. If there is no subscription to an Observable the logic of it won't be executed. See the details about `Observables` here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable

Comment: And also if you have subscriptions to `Observable` objects don't forget to unsubscribe from them to avoid potential memory leaks. See a nice summary about this topic here: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your time! It is clear now.